# Finding shortest Path in maze with co-ordinates

Tags: java, shortest-path, maze

Hey I'm a beginner i wrote program which is looking for shortest way, from start to end in 2 dimensional array. But my problem is that i can't find Full Path with co-ordinalte. I mean for example in that :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {


    int[][] pom = new int[4][4];


    int arr[][] =
            {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}};


    int startX = 3;
    int startY = 1;
    int endX = 2;
    int endY = 3;

    int min_dist = shortestPath(arr, pom, startX, startY, endX, endY, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0);

    System.out.println(min_dist);

}
```

I woulkd like to get on output : (3,1),(3,2),(2,2),(2,3)

This is my method for that, Im trying to do that with list , but still dont have idea how to do  that and how to properly clear them during process
(Class Point has only 2 atrributes, int x and int y)

```
  static List<Point> tmp = new ArrayList<>();


public static boolean uCanGo(int mat[][], int visited[][], int x, int y) {

    if (mat[x][y] == 1 && visited[x][y] == 0) {
        //   tmp.add(new Point(x, y));

        return true;

    }


    return false;
}


public static int shortestPath(int arr[][], int visited[][], int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int finalDistance, int currentDistance) {
    if (startX == endX && startY == endY) {

        return Integer.min(finalDistance, currentDistance);

    }
    visited[startX][startY] = 1;



    if ((startY + 1 < 4) && uCanGo(arr, visited, startX, startY + 1)) {
        finalDistance = shortestPath(arr, visited, startX, startY + 1, endX, endY, finalDistance, currentDistance + 1);
    }
    if ((startX + 1 < 4) && uCanGo(arr, visited, startX + 1, startY)) {


        finalDistance = shortestPath(arr, visited, startX + 1, startY, endX, endY, finalDistance, currentDistance + 1);

    }
    if ((startX - 1 > 0) && uCanGo(arr, visited, startX - 1, startY)) {


        finalDistance = shortestPath(arr, visited, startX - 1, startY, endX, endY, finalDistance, currentDistance + 1);

    }
    if ((startY - 1 > 0) && uCanGo(arr, visited, startX, startY - 1)) {

        finalDistance = shortestPath(arr, visited, startX, startY - 1, endX, endY, finalDistance, currentDistance + 1);
    }
    visited[startX][startY] = 0;
    return finalDistance;
}
```

Sorry for problem and thanks

After help, i still cant find problem for example in that array there should be : (3,3)(4,3)(5,3)(6,3)(6,4)(6,5)

```
       int arr[][] =
                        {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                        {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                        {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                        {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                };

        int startX = 3;
        int startY = 3;
        int endX = 6;
        int endY = 5;
```

Comment: Please narrow down your question further to specific problem you are facing. This seems like an algorithm question and some users at SO might wrongly suspect it is a homework problem.

Comment: If you want to find shortest path, you should do a breadth-first search.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wanted a path I changed the returntype of your method and made some minor changes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arr[][] = { { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 } };

    int startX = 3;
    int startY = 1;
    int endX = 2;
    int endY = 3;

    List<Point> path = new ArrayList<>();
    path.add(new Point(startX, startY));
    List<Point> foundPath = shortestPath(arr, startX, startY, endX, endY, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, path);

    for (Point p : foundPath) {
        System.out.print("(" + p.x + "," + p.y + "), ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean uCanGo(int mat[][], List<Point> visited, int x, int y) {
    if (mat[x][y] == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (Point p : visited) {
        if (p.x == x && p.y == y) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static List<Point> shortestPath(int arr[][], int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int finalDistance,
        int currentDistance, List<Point> visited) {
    if (startX == endX && startY == endY) {
        return visited;
    }

    if ((startY + 1 < 4) && uCanGo(arr, visited, startX, startY + 1)) {
        List<Point> nextPath = new ArrayList<>(visited);
        nextPath.add(new Point(startX, startY + 1));
        return shortestPath(arr, startX, startY + 1, endX, endY, finalDistance, currentDistance + 1, nextPath);
    }
    if ((startX + 1 < 4) && uCanGo(arr, visited, startX + 1, startY)) {
        List<Point> nextPath = new ArrayList<>(visited);
        nextPath.add(new Point(startX + 1, startY));
        return shortestPath(arr, startX + 1, startY, endX, endY, finalDistance, currentDistance + 1, nextPath);

    }
    if ((startX - 1 > 0) && uCanGo(arr, visited, startX - 1, startY)) {
        List<Point> nextPath = new ArrayList<>(visited);
        nextPath.add(new Point(startX - 1, startY));
        return shortestPath(arr, startX - 1, startY, endX, endY, finalDistance, currentDistance + 1, nextPath);

    }
    if ((startY - 1 > 0) && uCanGo(arr, visited, startX, startY - 1)) {
        List<Point> nextPath = new ArrayList<>(visited);
        nextPath.add(new Point(startX, startY - 1));
        return shortestPath(arr, startX, startY - 1, endX, endY, finalDistance, currentDistance + 1, nextPath);
    }
    return visited;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but when increased array to 10x10 and choose another start and end points  I have bad result , I edited my post .

Comment: Maybe you should try the hard way and debug. Check what your program is doing at every step and if it goes an unexpected way think about it. That is what I would do. I will not do it for you because this will need potentially a lot of time.